# How to intercept IRB input?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to intercept IRB inputs? Specifically for class#Fixnum?

Example:

```
5
=> 5
```

What I need to do is: *(pseudo code)*

```
if IRB.input.is_a?(Fixnum)
  some_method(IRB.input)  # some_method(5)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [file](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_1/lib/irb.rb#L473).
You can find Irb#eval_input method and patch them:

```
# code before
@scanner.set_input(@context.io) do
  signal_status(:IN_INPUT) do
    if l = @context.io.gets
      if l.match(/^\d+$/)
        puts 'Integer found!'
      end
      print l if @context.verbose?
    else
      if @context.ignore_eof? and @context.io.readable_after_eof?
        l = "\n"
        if @context.verbose?
          printf "Use \"exit\" to leave %s\n", @context.ap_name
        end
      else
        print "\n"
      end
    end
    l
  end
end
# code after
```

Irb output example:

```
spark@think:~$ irb
2.1.5 :001 > 123
Integer found!
 => 123 
2.1.5 :002 > "string"
 => "string"
```